# scanf is returning 2, not true

Tags: c, return, scanf

```
int main(void){
    float f=0,ff=0;
    if (scanf("%f %f",&f,&ff) == 2){
        printf("True\n%f %f",f,ff);fflush(stdout);
    } else{
        printf("False\n%f %f",f,ff);fflush(stdout);
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

If my input is "6.81 7.kj" it returns true!!

Comment: `7.` is a valid float. The fact that there's more input left is irrelevant to the success of the call.

Comment: @Flexo That should probably be answer.

Comment: @Flexo Thanks. I just checked putting more numbers and charecter at "ff" and scanf() worked as expected. That means you're right.

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` has undefined behavior. Just delete that line.

Comment: You might want to re-word your title. `scanf` is returning 2, not true.

Comment: @KeithThompson

Thanks for the advice. Title changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`7.` is a valid float. The fact that there's more input left is irrelevant to the success of the call.